# Можно ли посредством JS реализовать в аудио плеере баланс звука левый правый канал?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование

Аудио плеер для сайта, не используется ни каких плагинов, собрано на чистом JS, CSS и HTML... Собран собственноручно... Аудио файлы подгружаются с сервера. Сервер nodejs.  Плеер три в одном...  АУДИО, ВИДЕО И РАДИО...  Вот по ходу сборки пришла идея, сделать баланс звука, если честно, не видел нигде помимо десктопных приложений. Может есть возможность реализовать это, если не на клиентской стороне, а может на сервере nodejs?  Не прошу писать код за меня, но если это реально осуществить, просто подскажите в каком направлении двигаться... И чего почитать... Если конечно это возможно реализовать! Заранее благодарствую.

P.S. Рассматриваю даже экспериментальное API...

Comment: Любопытство не порок, а образ жизни)))  крайне интересно, за что вопросу минус? что именно не так с вопросом? не понятен, не интересен или задан не так как надо...

Comment: Можете и баланс собственноручно сделать - декодировать сначала в PCM, умножить семплы каналов на коэффициент, и воспроизвести.

Comment: Vladimir Gamalyan, стало любопытно, но если честно, я не понял ничего, можно поподробней, потому что, мне JS дается с трудом, все еще грызу этот гранит...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На данный момент нет такой опции в спецификации html5. Возможно есть некоторые экпериментальные API в некоторых браузерах, но они ещё не доведены до ума, так что я думаю что стандартными способами баланс звука сделать не получится.

Но кажется что с https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js это сделать всё таки можно